# After Effects: Moving Protected Areas from a parent compositions in time

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting, motion-graphics

I recently learned about the neat responsive design feature in after effects called "protected areas". While understanding the need and basic functionality of that feature, I am still wondering if there is a way to change the position of a protected area from a parent composition.

Example: I have a composition A with 3 protected areas. One at the start of the comp (intro animation), one at the end (outro animation) and one right in the middle of the comp (animation to visualize a state change). Now once I put comp A into another comp B, I can see my protected areas being higlighted in blue. If I drag and drop the end of my placed comp A, the comp's duration will stretch while remaining the duration of each protected area. However, the space between each protected area is always equal obviously. What I am trying to achieve is to shift the position of the centered protected area to the left or right. This way I would be able to place my state change animation whereever I need within my parent comp.

I hope my problem/wish gets clear and one of you has a solution in mind to tackle it.